# Detecting Errors in Windows 8 CMD Scripts that have If statement

Tags: cmd

I have noticed what looks like a bug in Windows. I have a simple console application that returns -12. And a .cmd script that checks the return value using ERRORLEVEL and %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0. The script always works when the check is not nested inside an IF statement. When it is nested inside the IF statement, the return value detected by the script changes each time the script is ran. First time the script does not detect an error. The 2nd time, the script correctly detects error -12. On 3rd and subsequent runs, the script reports error 1.

Here is the script:

```
    @echo off

    IF "%1" NEQ "" (

    ECHO RUNNING %1
    %1
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
     ECHO %1 returned positive value %ERRORLEVEL%
     EXIT /B 1
    )

    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
     ECHO %1 returned %ERRORLEVEL%
     EXIT /B 1
    )
   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **setlocal enabledelayedexpansion**.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
if "%1" NEQ "" (
  echo running %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7
  %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7
  if errorlevel 1 (
    echo %1 returned positive value !ERRORLEVEL!
    exit /b 1
  )
  if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
    echo %1 returned !ERRORLEVEL!
    exit /b 1
  )
)
endlocal
```